Asserting RxJS function returns
I am struggling to assert the response of some RxJS functions of and throwError.
// example.test.ts
import { equal } from "assert";
import { example } from "./example";
import { of, throwError } from "rxjs";

const errorObservable = exampleThrow(new Error("Test"));
const emptyObservable = exampleOf(new Error("Test"));

equal(errorObservable, new Observable(() => new Error("Test")); // Invalid
equal(emptyObservable, new Observable(() => {})); // Fails

equal(errorObservable, new Observable(throwError(() => error)); // Fails
equal(emptyObservable, of({})); // Fails

// example.ts
import { of, throwError } from "rxjs";

const export exampleThrow = (error) => {
  return throwError(() => error);
}

const export exampleOf = (error) => {
  return of({});
}


I would suggest you don't mock RxJS functions - in general, don't mock what you don't own. It's hard so say how you should test whatever you're working on, as example seems a bit pointless, but generally you'd test using of and from to create observables and assert on e.g. emitted values (some examples from a little assertion helper I wrote: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjest#toemit).

@jonrsharpe You are completely correct, I wasn't thinking. I have completely rewritten the question to be more accurate.

This still doesn't make a lot of sense to me - why would you expect reference equality of two completely different observable objects?! See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/73842839/3001761 - you need to think about testing the behaviour, what they emit or error with, when they complete.

I am completely new to the world of observables, I need to RTFM it seems. The link you provided is a good start. What are the gotchas to @customcommander's answer in that linked thread?
